# How to interpret value returned by ComponentGetFontAttributes?

Tags: fonts, annotations, dm-script

The title is the whole question. It seems the value returned is always an 8-bit integer. What does each bit represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned value is an integer value representing a binary mask mapping onto the font properties:

[image: Anno]

```c
number bold = 0xF
number italic = 0x10
number underlined  = 0x20
number strike = 0x40

image test := realImage("Test",4,200,200)
test.ShowImage()
ImageDisplay disp = test.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
component text = NewTextAnnotation(10,10, "Some text", 20)
disp.ComponentAddChildAtEnd(text)

text.ComponentSetFontAttributes( italic + underlined + strike + bold )
```

Comment: Very clear example. Thank you. If I understand correctly, it seems there is no way to get a shadowed/outlined font, as is used in the scale bar?

Comment: @MikeKundmann To my knowledge, correct.